# What's the purpose of having a ViewContext property on a Tag Helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, viewcontext, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have 2 questions: 

 1. what is Viewcontext and what are its advantages?
 2. why we have to use it in tag helpers?

Actually i am the beginner and follow the "Pro ASP.NET Core MVC,6th Edition"  by adam freeman in this he make a taghelper class in which he uses

```
 [ViewContext]
 [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
 public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
```

He didn't explain the above piece of code why he uses these properties in square brackets purpose of these properties.
And please share a link which describe about these type of properties if any

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `ViewContext` object is the object that provides access to things like the HttpContext, HttpRequest, HttpResponse and so on.  The way that you can gain access to it in a TagHelper is via a property but in such a case you need to set the `[ViewContext]` attribute so that the property gets set to the current `ViewContext`.

So for example you can gain access to the current request via the following:

```
 var currentRequest = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request;
```

`[HtmlAttributeNotBound]` basically says that this attribute isn't one that you intend to set via a tag helper attribute in the html.

Your tag helper may not need access to the `ViewContext` object and all it's subobjects.  If not, you can omit the ViewContext property and associated attributes from your `TagHelper`.  It's certainly not a required property for a `TagHelper` and most of my own tag helpers so far have not needed access to it.